# Error printing string formatted with %.0f using an int substitute

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am trying to print the string in `toString()`.  It prints fine if I remove the `%.0f` and the `this.years` substitute, but does not print if I include it.  I am not sure why.  The only reason I can think of is perhaps it is because years is an `int`, and my string formatting only works with `doubles`?

How can I change the code so that I can substitute the `%.0f` with `this.years`?

```
// instance members
private double amountBorrowed;
private double yearlyRate;
private int years;
public double A;
public double n = years * 12;

// public instance method
public MyLoan(double amt, double rt, int yrs) {
    this.amountBorrowed = amt;
    this.yearlyRate = rt;
    this.years = yrs;
    this.n = yrs * 12;

public String toString() {

    String temp1 = String.format("Loan: $%.2f at %.2f for %.0f years.", this.amountBorrowed, this.yearlyRate, this.years);
    return temp1;
```

The error I receive when trying to print is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at hw2.MyLoan.toString(MyLoan.java:61)
    at hw2.MyLoan.main(MyLoan.java:101)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use '%d' instead of '%.0f' for formating 'int'.

For more about formatting see here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: It worked!!  That answered the question, thank you!!  I knew it was probably just the wrong formatting.  Thanks again!